# Is MP3 mixing possible?

Tags: audio, mp3

For 2 mp3 streams, is it possible to mix two streams of same bitrate with different mixdown values without uncompressing and recompressing it?

For example, if we have two songs that are already encoded in mp3 192 kbit, and we want to create crossfade of length 5 seconds, we should mix last several frames from one song with same number of frames from the second song, with mix rates increasing from 0 to 100 for entering song and from 100 to 0 for closing one.

Comment: I'm guessing you can't use Audacity or Garage Band to produce the final product?

Comment: No, I am talking about programmaticaly mixing it, for god's sake. It's stack overflow we are on, right?

Comment: Unless you're working with a hardware decoder, it gets sent to the soundcard as uncompressed samples anyway. Just decode it, mix it, and send it to the sound buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, the mp3-compression goes VERY ROUGHLY something like this:

1. takes a frame of samples
2. converts them to frequency range
3. drops frequencies which are below a certain threshold (which is the compression)

So if you only have the mp3-data, you should have chunks/frames of frequencies (with index). To mix the streams you'd have to take the corresponding frames from each stream and construct a new frame that e.g. consist of f(idx) = fA(idx) + fB(idx) /2. Be aware that the frames have different lengths, because not all indices (idx) are present, which is because some frequencies are drop for the compression. I hope that helps for the beginning. I'm aware that this is not a full on solution.

Comment: My thoughts are exactly on that - but there are some issues (many of them) to be concerned with.  I know that somewhere in the frame there are freq-domain data that CAN be mixed.  But, later, some part of new frame should be dropped, and so on...

Comment: @Daniel M.: I don't think you would want to drop "parts of the new frame", since the results should always be above the threshold. The only way I can imagine is, if you have interference due to a difference in the phase of the same(!) frequency in the two original files. But if you are able to find a document telling you about the data structure of MP3-files, you can easily see if you have phase information. And if so, you can make use of that and then maybe drop some frequencies. However the adding should also work without dropping frequencies. You'd only lack the (extra) compression.